# Installing and using a specific font in a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, installation

I want to use a specific font in my winform app. This font will be auto installed in user personal computer from my application resource.

How can I do that?

I used some code which is from user personal computer. If I use this the `font` must be remain previously in user personal computer but I don't want that.

```
         System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new     System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
         fontCollection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\SUTOM__.TTF");
         FontFamily family = new FontFamily("SutonnyMJ", fontCollection);
         Font font3of9 = new Font(family, 15);
         label1.Font = font3of9;
```

Answer (score 8):

**1. Install Using Setup Project**

You can install font from your setup project to do this you have to

> File System > Right Click under the File System on Target Machine > Add Special Folder Fonts Folder

Then Select Fonts Folder and `Add > File...`
[image: Add Font Folder SS]

**2. Install Font Programmatically**
To achive this you have to do some external calls unfortunately.

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint="AddFontResourceW", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int AddFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                         string lpFileName);
```

Then call it from anywhere you want

```
AddFontResource(@"C:\FontLocation\MyFont.TTF");
```

Comment: +1 for the first part. About the second part, AddFontResource adds the font only temporarily, until reboot. (See Remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326(v=vs.85).aspx)).