# Do I need to install missing fonts on client machine for Windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I am working on a C# Windows application and have got the Wireframe Layouts from the client. The client specifically wants the text to be rendered in a particular font that is quite rare. I have got the font installed on my development machine and the text is showing up properly on it. Do I have to install that font on the client machine during the installation or my application will handle it automatically?

Comment: I think you have to bring that rare font with your installation package, install that font when user setting up or at the first time your application runs.

Comment: [Already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007805/embedding-deploying-custom-font-in-net-app)

Comment: The `wonko79's link` is what you need. Loading font that way is done easily without having to install that font into the target machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

(while creating setup)right click on the File System on Target Machine, Add Special Folder -> give that folder name "Fonts" Folder, then place your font file there.

it will place your fonts in client system where fonts are installed i.e. C:\Windows\Fonts folder of client machine.Yes this is done manually while making setup. check this link once

[Installing and using a specific font in a winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231091/installing-and-using-a-specific-font-in-a-winform)

In the diagram font is added programatically but you don't need to do that, you can also add font manually, just put the font in that special folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to deploy the font with your application, it will not be done automatically.

Also, be wary of licensing problems, as many fonts are not free to distribute.