# C# Font type missing

Tags: c#, fonts

I just tried my application on WinXP and discovered that the font type is not the type I set while developing (on Win7)!
Seems like fonts are related to user system (I thought it's related  to .NET Framework version - which would be much logical solution since all users need same framework version to run my application)... Anyway, what are my options now for my app to look the same on every system?? Can I just distribute and install the missing fonts with my app, or is there a better solution... HELP!

Comment: You can install (or remove) fonts from your system as you wish.  So there is no telling who has what fonts on their workstation.  If you are not using one of the common font (Like Arial, Verdana) you have two options.  You can install the font you want to use as part of the setup and deployment or you can add it programmatically.  see the SO post for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231091/installing-and-using-a-specific-font-in-a-winform

Comment: You are running your app on a 13 year old operating system.  Typography has made a few strides since then, Vista and Win7 had many significant additions.  They are protected by copyright, you can buy them from a type foundry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are certain rights the user should have to be able to install fonts on a system.

Refer to [this blog](http://blog.megahard.info/2010/08/use-font-without-installing.html) on how to use custom fonts without installing.

Comment: This works great! Thank You.
Can I use fonts this way freely or do I need some permissions to put .ttf files as resources in my installer (fonts are Consolas and Segoe Print)?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I'll use free fonts.